# Не запускается MySQL на Debian 8

Tags: mysql, debian

Почему-то не работает MySQL на Debian 8. Вырезка из логов:

```
● mysql.servicesystemctl.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

● status.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: No such file or directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)

● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2015-09-06 15:59:58 MSK; 3min 20s ago
  Process: 26305 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 06 15:59:27 pingcheck mysql[26305]: /etc/init.d/mysql: WARNING: /etc/mysql/my.cnf cannot be read. See README.Debian.gz ... (warning).
Sep 06 15:59:27 pingcheck /etc/init.d/mysql[26314]: WARNING: /etc/mysql/my.cnf cannot be read. See README.Debian.gz
Sep 06 15:59:58 pingcheck /etc/init.d/mysql[26749]: 0 processes alive and '/usr/bin/mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping' resulted in
Sep 06 15:59:58 pingcheck /etc/init.d/mysql[26749]: Could not open required defaults file: /etc/mysql/debian.cnf
Sep 06 15:59:58 pingcheck /etc/init.d/mysql[26749]: Fatal error in defaults handling. Program aborted
Sep 06 15:59:58 pingcheck /etc/init.d/mysql[26749]:
Sep 06 15:59:58 pingcheck mysql[26305]: Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
Sep 06 15:59:58 pingcheck systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Sep 06 15:59:58 pingcheck systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon.
Sep 06 15:59:58 pingcheck systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.
```

Как это поправить?

Comment: а в своих логах что *mysqld* пишет?

Comment: 150906 15:55:36 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.

Comment: 150906 15:55:37 [ERROR] Fatal error: Can't open and lock privilege tables: Table 'mysql.host' doesn't exist

Comment: mysql_upgrade не работает. Отдаёт ошибку "Upgrade failed"

Answer (score 1):

Как ставили mysql? Почему у вас нет ни `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`, ни `/etc/mysql/debian.cnf` файлов? Судя по-всему он не может найти конфиги и радостно падает на бок.

Варианта два:

- Хороший: положить ему конфиги туда, где он их ищет - в папку `/etc/mysql`
- Плохой: поправить скрипт `/etc/init.d/mysql` (параметр CONF), чтобы он искал конфиги там, где вы их положили. После обновления опять все сломается.

Answer (score 0):

Не могу пока писать комментарии, но это должно быть комментарием.

Что у вас за база? Обновление с прошлой версии mysql? Используйте `mysql_upgrade`, как логи и советуют.

`mysql.host` недоступна - это после обновления?

В общем, лучший способ перенести данные между mysql разных версий - `mysqldump`.

В отсутствии возможности это сделать - можно пробовать при помощи `mysql_upgrade`.